# Что в данном коде не так? Хочу узнать ,является ли введенная буква равной из букве из списка?

Tags: python, алгоритм, функции, list

```py
word=list ["a", "e", "i","o" ,"u"]
word_rus = (str(input("Введите слово: ")))

def check( word_rus, ):
    if word_rus in word:
        print("гласная")
   
check()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, при объявлении списков в Python **не нужно** писать дополнительно `list`, просто список вполне сойдёт.

Во-вторых, Вы объявили функцию с одним аргументом `word_rus`, однако позднее вызываете эту же функцию без каких-либо аргументов. Тут нужно либо добавить аргумент в вызов (лучше также убрать запятую после аргументов), либо избавиться от аргументов вовсе (так тоже будет работать, т.к. переменные одноимённые).

```py
word= ["a", "e", "i","o" ,"u"]
word_rus = (str(input("Введите слово: ")))

def check():
    if word_rus in word:
        print("гласная")
   
check()
```

Наконец, можно просто избавиться от функции и проверять всё сразу, без объявлений и т.п.:

```py
word= ["a", "e", "i","o" ,"u"]
word_rus = (str(input("Введите слово: ")))

if word_rus in word:
  print("гласная")
```

Comment: Весь ответ пронизан антипаттернами, тип указывать **нужно** но не обязательно, избавляться от функции - нужно не всегда, если критична производительность - можно заинлайнить, но не убирать